# Allow traffic only from referrer url

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 websites. On website 1 im showing my entire website 2 in iframe. I want to block access to website 2 except if traffic is coming from website 1. I have tried something in httaccess file but it doesn't seem to work. 
This is on webcite 2.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://www.1.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: A simple look into the documentation shows that the `${HTTP_REFERER}` does _not_ include the protocol scheme, but only the host name: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html   When will people finally start reading the documentation of the tools the use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did opposite, please try below rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# block referers which are not www.1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^www.1.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: how do I "# block referrers which are not www.1.com"

Comment: It doesnt do anything.
I have tried this and it failed it doesnt load the page from website 1 nor from anywhere.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?1.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]

Comment: i have make ti to work with this RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.1.com/
RewriteRule .* - [F]
but it doesnt display images